# The duplicate button is a duplicate

Tags: support, flags

In the triage queue, when clicking on "unsalvageable" there's an option sayin "a duplicate".

[image]

But I can also click on "should be closed" and mark the question as a dupe.

Why is that? Is there any difference between those two options?

Comment: It's actually just the standard flagging dialog. Triage doesn't use a separate close link.

Comment: The duplicate button is duplicated? How meta.

Comment: Do it, but choose the correct duplicate button to flag the question as a duplicate. @psubsee2003

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The duplication notice is likely repeated there for convenience; instead of making you click through twice to close as a dupe, you can click through once instead.  The modal is being reused, as there's no difference between the regular close modal and the one you get when you select "should be closed".

Comment: Ok perfect, thank you!